# Powershell : How to check if there is a copy job in progress using powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to use PowerShell monitor a drive (Like c:) for moving jobs?
I want to write a script for moving one file at a time.
FileSystemWatcher doesn't do this.

Comment: I'm sorry but, can you rephrase what you're asking?

Comment: For the entire drive?

Comment: I've been giving it a thought any you might be interested in NTFS auditing:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder

Comment: This question needs quite some clarification: 1. if you only want to monitor jobs that you are starting, that drastically simplifies the issue, 2. if only you are moving files, then why not do it in one script looping through them one at a time as you mention, and then you don't need to monitor anything?